# Good approach for installing Openstack on Xen

Tags: virtualization, xen, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I'm new to Openstack and I've one physical server with `Xen` installed on it .. My idea is :
I want to use `openstack` in order to create compute instances on my server (Xen)

but actually i'm not sure about the right infrastructure for accomplishing that ..

As per my understood :

- I'll create an instance on my `Xen` (DomU) in order to install `Openstack` controller (Horizon GUI)
- I'll use `Dom0` for `Xen` as a `Compute` node for creating the instances
- I don't know what else to do

Is this infrastructure is right, safe and secure ?

OR

- I've to keep `Dom0` as it's away from any thing
- Keeping each `Component` for `Opentack` isolated on a separated Instance ?
- Or i've to put the `Openstack` controller Outside the whole `Xen` container in order to use the server as a purely `Compute`

Appreciate your clarification

Comment: At least for the initial installation, the undercloud has to be outside the intended VM hosts. You can move it in later.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so you mean it's right to install both of the controller and the Compute on the same Dom0 ?

Comment: For a small little proof of concept you could certainly do that. It obviously won't be enough for production though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks a lot, actually it's a type of learning the technology in addition to i'll create two or three Instances for small business use

Comment: Personally I would dump Xen and start over with a clean server and an [RDO](https://www.rdoproject.org/) installation with Packstack. While you _can_ use OpenStack with Xen, the learning curve is a lot higher, as KVM is the default hypervisor and Xen has a lot of idiosyncrasies. And you can easily move from Packstack to a production TripleO installation later if you want.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks a lot .. i moved to use KVM and now i've installed Openstack controller, keystone , horizon and working on installing the rest .. is this the right way ? or i've to use TripleO ? is it better in long term for maintenance and creating VMs? or i keep my way with Openstack directly and its components better ? what are the challenges that i may face if i used openstack directly ? your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a clean install of Openstack, and select Xen as default hypervisor.

Aside from all-in-one proofs of concept (like packstack or devstack), you will need minimum two hosts: one controller node and one compute node (in the compute node is where the hypervisor will be located, in this case Xen).

Comment: Regarding the best way to install OpenStack, manually or using a "helper", I would really choose the second way. TripleO, Kolla (using Kubernetes), Ansible OpenStack, juju (from Cannonical) are splendid tools that can help you install and mantain an OpenStack installation. @Jason4Ever

Comment: Forgot to mention crowbar from Suse